# Data vanishing in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm getting crash reports from a large percentage of my user base, and have tracked it down to a core data entity having every record deleted somehow.

This entity is one where the app downloads every row the first time you launch the app, and then the table is never written to again, it's just a read only lookup table.

It shouldn't be possible for anything to ever be removed from the entity, but that's what I'm seeing. All reports are the app functions fine for a while (sometimes days, other times minutes after a fresh install) and then suddenly starts crashing any time you try to do anything.

I've gone over the entire code base and nothing ever deletes data from the entity. The bug only occurs in a version of the app just released. Rolling all users back to the previous release - only two weeks old, has fixed the bug for for everyone. It's an enterprise app, I simply redeployed the old binary.

I went over every change in source control and found nothing related to the entity.

In fact all code related to this entity has not changed at all in the last few years. It's been perfectly stable all that time.

Other data is persisted to disk in the same `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` call, and that data does not vanish.

I'm stumped. How can data in an entity be erased? How can I debug this issue further?

I am unable to reproduce the bug on my own devices, although I have extensive logging in place (and am happy to add more — this is an enterprise app only ever used for work so user privacy isn't an issue).

Comment: Show us crash logs please. Maybe you use one context in concurrent threads? It may cause random crashes.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin The crash is an object being nil that should never be nil. It's trying to find a record in core data that does not exist. The app shows a splash screen on first launch while it downloads the data, then saves it to disk, then you can start using it. A few minutes or days later the data has vanished.

Comment: Do you delete other entities ? Are you sure one of the `NSFetchRequest`s isn't mistakenly querying the wrong entityName ?

Comment: @BartVandendriessche there are a couple places that delete from other entities but only 3 or 4 places and I've gone over it carefully to verify it is deleting from the correct entity. Also, none of that code has changed between when the bug started occurring. Finally, I have verified (complicated to explain) that none of that deletion code is executing for users who have experienced this bug.

Comment: Other entities are only deleted when the server instructs the iOS device to delete them. I have logs of all client/server communication and no such command is being sent.

Comment: You could register for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` which has a set of deleted objects under `NSDeletedObjects` in its userInfo. If that set contains objects that should never be deleted, maybe you could log some sensible context information.

At least you'd be able to tell if this data is actually deleted via regular CoreData means.

Comment: Do the downloaded entity objects ever persist? Are you able to observe whether the download is successful prior to persistence and again whether the downloaded data is properly mapped to the core data Entity prior to persistence?

Comment: Presumably if anything at all in the context is persisted everything should be persisted? Why would just one entity fail to persist?

Comment: Maybe the data does not download correctly, or maybe the downloaded data is not properly applied to the `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: @andrewbuilder as a debugging measure I'm storing a copy of the downloaded JSON data in the same database as the one this entity is stored in, so I know it downloaded correctly. Also the app was functional after it downloaded then ceased to be functional later on. The app can't function at all without the data being properly applied, you tap anything on the main screen and it crashes unless  the data is in place.

Comment: Forgive me, but to understand correctly the data downloads ok, so is the downloaded data, or part of the downloaded data then used to provide values for the the entity's attributes before you attempt to persist?

Comment: The downloaded data is just an array of thousands of records across 15 or so entities that are inserted into the `NSManagedObjectContext` and then the context is saved. The JSON structure matches the core data structure perfectly. At some later point, one of the entities has every record deleted somehow.

Comment: Is it by any chance the last record that is deleted, or just a random record?

Comment: @andrewbuilder it's the first entity to be inserted into a previously empty database. All records in the entity vanish later.